# Android: Highlight effect on image programatically

Tags: android, image, java-2d

Is there any way to highlight tab icon image programmatically without using separate drawable resource?

I tried using PorterDuffColorFilter but it doesn't look good:

```
// apply a color mask to the icon to mark it as selected
int selectedIconMaskColor = view.getResources().getColor(R.color.tab_icon_selected);
PorterDuffColorFilter selectedIconFilter = new PorterDuffColorFilter(selectedIconMaskColor,
  PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
copyIconDrawable.setColorFilter(selectedIconFilter);
```

Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: rather than doing this complex,create selector file and change image when selected,will give the highlight effect efficiently

Comment: you just have to pass xml instead of drawable,thats it.

Comment: yes, I agree. The thing is when doing same app for Android and iOS, we usually get the tab icons for iOS which does it's own highlighting and do not get separate highlighted icons for Android. I wrote this code to produce similar effect on Android like the iOS tab icon highlighting.

Comment: whatever is achieved in iOS by default is not possible by default in Android.but yes it can be made customly.My point is if it is possible in a easier way than why to do it in tedious manner.Android do have some limitations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using simple image manipulation class:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;

/**
 * Image with support for filtering.
 */
public class FilteredImage {

  private Bitmap image;

  private int width;

  private int height;

  private int[] colorArray;

  /**
   * Constructor.
   * 
   * @param img the original image
   */
  public FilteredImage(Bitmap img) {
    this.image = img;
    width = img.getWidth();
    height = img.getHeight();

    colorArray = new int[width * height];
    image.getPixels(colorArray, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

    applyHighlightFilter();
  }

  /**
   * Get the color for a specified pixel.
   * 
   * @param x x
   * @param y y
   * @return color
   */
  public int getPixelColor(int x, int y) {
    return colorArray[y * width + x];
  }

  /**
   * Gets the image.
   * 
   * @return Returns the image.
   */
  public Bitmap getImage() {
    return image;
  }

  /**
   * Applies green highlight filter to the image.
   */
  private void applyHighlightFilter() {
    int a;
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {

        int c = getPixelColor(x, y);

        a = Color.alpha(c);
        r = Color.red(c);
        g = Color.green(c);
        b = Color.blue(c);

        r = (int) (r * 0.8);
        g = (int) (g * 1.6);
        b = (int) (b * 0.8);

        if (r > 255) {
          r = 255;
        }
        if (r < 0) {
          r = 0;
        }
        if (g > 255) {
          g = 255;
        }
        if (g < 0) {
          g = 0;
        }
        if (b > 255) {
          b = 255;
        }
        if (b < 0) {
          b = 0;
        }

        int resultColor = Color.argb(a, r, g, b);
        image.setPixel(x, y, resultColor);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this code which works perfectly and performs faster. Hope this'll help future readers.

```
public static Bitmap highlightImage(Bitmap src) {
    // create new bitmap, which will be painted and becomes result image
    Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(src.getWidth() + 96, src.getHeight() + 96, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    // setup canvas for painting
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOut);
    // setup default color
    canvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
    // create a blur paint for capturing alpha
    Paint ptBlur = new Paint();
    ptBlur.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(15, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL));
    int[] offsetXY = new int[2];
    // capture alpha into a bitmap
    Bitmap bmAlpha = src.extractAlpha(ptBlur, offsetXY);
    // create a color paint
    Paint ptAlphaColor = new Paint();
    ptAlphaColor.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    // paint color for captured alpha region (bitmap)
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmAlpha, offsetXY[0], offsetXY[1], ptAlphaColor);
    // free memory
    bmAlpha.recycle();

    // paint the image source
    canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);

    // return out final image
    return bmOut;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this, not best solution but works...

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imageView.setColorFilter(R.color.button_selection);
            doLater(SECOND / 3, new Run() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    imageView.setColorFilter(0x00000000);
                }
            });
            doClick(imageView);
        }
    });
```

And this is for some other view...

```
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            view.getBackground().setColorFilter(R.color.button_selection, Mode.SRC_OVER);
            view.getBackground().invalidateSelf();
            doLater(SECOND / 3, new Run() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    view.getBackground().setColorFilter(0x00000000, Mode.SRC_OVER);
                    view.getBackground().invalidateSelf();
                }
            });
            doClick(view);
        }
    });
```